# ListGrid / ListGridField - Hover message while editing

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Is there a way to show a hover message on an editable cell/ListGridField while in Edit mode?

Was able to have a hover message over a cell in non-edit mode by :

```
cusipField.setShowHover(true);
cusipField.setHoverCustomizer(getCusipHoverCustomizer());
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to manipulate the properties of the editor that is created when you enter edit mode for a field through an appropriate FormItem and the ListGridField.setEditorProperties(FormItem  editorProperties) method. For example, if your field is storing texts, you shall create a TextItem and define the hover text using its setPrompt(java.lang.String prompt) method. Then use that TextItem to set the editor properties for the field.